# Python changing Label Text depending on Optionmenu selection via button

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok here is the situation. 
I have a optionmenu with two values: eth0 & wlan0 (german for wifi) 
I have a button that triggers a function. In that function I check which option is selected and then it should change a Labels text. But when I click the button nothing happens. What am I missing?

Here´s the code:

Programm start:

```
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess


root = Tk()
#root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
root.geometry("480x320")
root.title("BabyDroid")

subprocess.call(["ip addr show eth0 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' > ip.txt"],shell=True)
ip_file= open("ip.txt")
textip = StringVar()
textip.set(ip_file.readline())
ip_file.close()
```

Dropdown menu:

```
network = StringVar(root)                                                           #Networkstatevariable for dropdown
network.set("eth0")                                                                 #default
networkmenu = OptionMenu(root,network,"eth0","wlan0").place(relx=0.8,rely=0.1)      #actual Dropdownmenu
```

Function:

```
def get_ip_address():
    global network
    global ip_file
    global textip
    if network.get() == "eth0":
        subprocess.call(["ip addr show eth0 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' > ip.txt"],shell=True)
        ip_file = open("/home/pi/RPi_Cam_Web_Interface/ip.txt")
        textip.set(ip_file.readline())
        ip_file.close()

    else:
        subprocess.call(["ip addr show wlan0 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' > ip.txt"],shell=True)
        ip_file= open("/home/pi/RPi_Cam_Web_Interface/ip.txt")
        textip.set(ip_file.readline())
        ip_file.close()
```

Label:

```
IPLabel = Label(root,textvariable=textip).place(relx=0.5,rely=0.1)
```

Button:

```
button4 = Button(root,text="Aktualisieren",fg="black",height=3,width=8,command=get_ip_address).place(relx=0.8,rely=0.2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tkinter, in order to retrieve a value from a dropdown menu, or any other widget that takes user input, you must use the get() function. Such as:

```
if network.get() == "eth0":
```

That is the only problem with your code that I have found so far.

Comment: Hey, thanks so far. I´ve changed it and now I get an error when I push the button: `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1535, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "index.py", line 43, in get_ip_address
    text.set(ip_file.readline())
NameError: global name 'text' is not defined`

Comment: Ben J. did his best, and with this rythm, whatever error a member fixes you will stumble on others for the simple reason the code you provided could not be debugged. Please read how to write an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) @Patrick260284

Comment: Found the error: used a wrong name for the global text in my function. Corrected my first post